# Running "git stash apply" after "git stash save --all", doesn't recover the tracked files but only the untracked ones

Tags: git

I have run `git stash save --all "XXXXX"` to stash some tracked files and one untracked file. After that, I have run `git stash apply stash@{0}` but the only file that has been recovered is the file that was untracked.

It looks like the rest of the files that have not been recovered (tracked files) were also stashed correctly because when I run `git stash show stash@{0}` I can see them.

Answer (score 0):

I had to modify the permissions/owner of those files and it worked.